# Redux - repeating object name

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is probably a mistake on my part but I've noticed that in my Redux store, for every entity, there seems to be an outer object named `x` which in turn has a child with the same name, which then contains the data.

This is better explained with an example:

**user reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  user: {},
}

const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        loggedIn: true,
      }
    case REGISTER_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        registered: true,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**user object in state**
[image: user in redux]

As you can see, `user` has a `user` nested inside of it.. can this pattern be avoided somehow in the reducer?

Comment: How are you reading it in `mapStateToProps` from `state`. And how is mapping in `combinedReducers` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your script on

```
case LOGIN_USER:
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.payload,
    loggedIn: true,
  }
```

etc..
it's should help you

Comment: thanks for the help! How would u solve this case if `user` inside `initialState` was an array? I can't do `...[...state.user, ...payload]` since that is incorrect. but I also don't want to do `user: [...state.user, ...payload]` since then I will go back to the same problem I had when I wrote the post..